# Am expecting a blue (red?) image from python-openCV, but get black

Tags: python, opencv

I'm just starting to use OpenCV with Python and am trying to do some simple things. To start with, I tried to create a solid Blue image (or possibly Red, if the image turns out to be RGB, instead of BGR).

I tried the following:

```
 import numpy as np
 import cv2

 img1 = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8) #Create black image
 img1[0,:,:] = 200 #Add intenstity to blue (red?) plane
 print img1 #Verify image array
 cv2.imshow("II",img1)
 cv2.waitKey(0)
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
 for _ in range (1,5):
     cv2.waitKey(1)
```

But, what I got was a black image. I'm fairly certain the array was correct, because the print statement gave me the following:

```
 [[[200 200 200]
  [200 200 200] 
  [200 200 200]
  ..., 
  [200 200 200]
  [200 200 200]
  [200 200 200]]

 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
   ..., 
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]

 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ..., 
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]

  ..., 
 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ..., 
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]

 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ..., 
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]

 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ..., 
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]]
```

Does it make sense that I'm seeing a black instead of a blue (or red?) image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is changing color of `0th row`. Instead, you need to change the values of first or 0th channel.

```
img[:, :, 0] = 255
```

This will change all the values of first or 0th channel to 255 which would give you blue image as it is a BGR Image.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the colors as a tuple ! if you want a `RGB` image because very Index in array is a pixel and you need 3 value for `B,G,R` ( opencv set the pixels as `BGR`)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img1 = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8) #Create black image
img1[:,:] = (255,0,0) #Add intenstity to blue (red?) plane
print img1 #Verify image array
cv2.imshow("II",img1,)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
for _ in range (1,5):
     cv2.waitKey(1)
```

result:

[image]

Comment: note that opencv assume pixels are stored as BGR not RGB

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realized I could assign down an array dimension like that.